# Is my old broadband router safe to throw out?

Tags: router, broadband

I recently switched ISPs, and my new ISP sent a new router/wi-fi unit. My old ISP doesn't want the old equipment back. I am now planning on taking it to an electronic waste recycling point.

But could there be any sensitive data stored on the devices? Caches or logs perhaps? If so, can I wipe them?

The devices are a BT Openreach branded "ECI Telecom" VDSL modem and a Plusnet branded  Technicolor TG582n wi-fi router.

Comment: If you are worried, power it up, and reset the device.

Answer (score 1):

The router's unlikely to have anything consequential - at most you'd store your SSID/password , and it *ought* to be safe, though doing a factory wipe or resetting them's not a bad idea

I've not used a VDSL router, but ADSL often has a username/password combination - any log ins for the ISP would be stored. I wouldn't particularly want that accessible in your shoes.

Chances are there's not really enough space in those cheap consumer devices for much caches or logs.

But yeah a factory wipe would handle any *casual* data leakages.